# What is wrong with this method? It is coming back false everytime

Tags: java, boolean

This method is supposed to check if the inputed number is a number and not a letter and then complete the function. However, every time I try it always is saying the input is wrong.

For example:

If I type in "5 * 5"

it says Error Incorrect Input
        Re-input your numbers:

when it shouldn't do anything. I can't figure it out.

My Code Is:

```
 public void multiply() throws IOException {       
    boolean valid = true;
    boolean valid1 = true;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    String string = input;
    String[] strings = string.split("\\*");
    String string1 = strings[0];
    String string2 = strings[1];
    for (valid = true; i < strings[0].length();) {
        if (strings[0].charAt(i) == '0'
                || strings[0].charAt(i) == '1'
                || strings[0].charAt(i) == '2'
                || strings[0].charAt(i) == '3'
                || strings[0].charAt(i) == '4'
                || strings[0].charAt(i) == '5'
                || strings[0].charAt(i) == '6'
                || strings[0].charAt(i) == '7'
                || strings[0].charAt(i) == '8'
                || strings[0].charAt(i) == '9'
                || strings[0].charAt(i) == '*') {
            valid = true;
        } else {
            valid = false;
        }
        i++;
    }
    for (valid1 = true; k < strings[1].length();) {
        if (strings[1].charAt(k) == '0'
                || strings[1].charAt(k) == '1'
                || strings[1].charAt(k) == '2'
                || strings[1].charAt(k) == '3'
                || strings[1].charAt(k) == '4'
                || strings[1].charAt(k) == '5'
                || strings[1].charAt(k) == '6'
                || strings[1].charAt(k) == '7'
                || strings[1].charAt(k) == '8'
                || strings[1].charAt(k) == '9'
                || strings[1].charAt(k) == '*') {
            valid1 = true;

        } else {
            valid1 = false;
        }
        k++;


         if (valid1 == true && valid == true) {
                 System.out.println("Multiply"); 
              //Going to finish
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error Incorrect Input");
                System.out.println("Re-input your numbers:");
                check();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop is wacky:  `for (valid = true; i < strings[0].length();) {` This looks like a cross between a while loop, a for loop and an if statement

Comment: When someone starts to number their variable names i run away.

Comment: You should break out of the loop as soon as one invalid character is detected. Otherwise, only the last character will have an effect on the result. As for your problem, could it be the space in `"5 "` when you split `"5 * 5"` into `"5 "` and  `" 5"`? (On another note: did you try to debug this by stepping through the execution?)

Comment: Even though the for loop's close is placed wrong this should not produce error. I think it is because of that you place a "space" between the number and "*" operator. Namely "5 * 5" might produce "5 ", "*", " 5" as tokens?

Comment: You should break out of your for loops whenever you set valid or valid1 to false, otherwise they can be set back to true next time through the same loop - as soon as you detect the bad input, set valid/valid1 to false and then break.  Also, don't write code like "if (a == true)", instead just write "if (a)".

Answer (score 2):

Let's reformat and simplify your code. First, we simplify the `blabla == '0' || blabla == '1' || ... || blabla == '9'` to `blabla >= '0' && blabla <= '9'`.

After that let's reduce `if (x) { y = true; } else { y = false; }` to `y = x;`.

Third, in your case, we can make the `i++` and `k++` inside the for-loops their increment expression, as they are incremented only once per iteration, in every iteration and not used for anything else after their increment.

Forth, if the fors are counting on some number, let's try to initialize them with these numbers. Initializing them with `valid = true` and `valid1 = true` is unnecessary as these variables already are true at that point.

Fifth using an expression like `x == true` when `x` is boolean can be reduced just to `x`.

Sixth, your `string` variable is useless as it is always the same as `input` is. Let's just use `input`.

Seventh, you are not using the variables `string1` and `string2` (instead, you are using `strings[0]` and `strings[1]`). Let's use them.

After these transforms, this is your code now:

```
 public void multiply() throws IOException {       
    boolean valid = true;
    boolean valid1 = true;
    String[] strings = input.split("\\*");
    String string1 = strings[0];
    String string2 = strings[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < string1.length(); i++) {
        valid = ((string1.charAt(i) >= '0' && string1.charAt(i) <= '9')
                || string1.charAt(i) == '*');
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < string2.length(); k++) {
        valid1 = ((string2.charAt(k) >= '0' && string2.charAt(k) <= '9')
                || string2.charAt(k) == '*');

        if (valid1 && valid) {
            System.out.println("Multiply"); 
            //Going to finish
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error Incorrect Input");
            System.out.println("Re-input your numbers:");
            check();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, we can easily spot some problems:

- The `if (valid1 && valid)` (originally `if (valid1 == true && valid == true)`) is inside the second for loop. Is this really intended? I think not. Move it to outside your loop.
- You reset the `valid` and `valid1` in your loops, regardless of their previous values. This is equivalent to just check the last char. What you really intended is that `valid` and `valid1` should be true only when every char is valid.
- Since you are spliting the `input` variable using the `"\\*"` regex, you will never get `*` in any of the generated Strings, so you don't have any need to check this.
- You are not filtering out spaces.

Let's fix these problems:

```
 public void multiply() throws IOException {       
    boolean valid = true;
    boolean valid1 = true;
    String[] strings = input.split("\\*");
    String string1 = strings[0].trim();
    String string2 = strings[1].trim();
    for (int i = 0; i < string1.length(); i++) {
        valid &= string1.charAt(i) >= '0' && string1.charAt(i) <= '9';
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < string2.length(); k++) {
        valid1 &= string2.charAt(k) >= '0' && string2.charAt(k) <= '9';
    }

    if (valid1 && valid) {
        System.out.println("Multiply"); 
        //Going to finish
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error Incorrect Input");
        System.out.println("Re-input your numbers:");
        check();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2426083: In addition to these excellent recommendations, I suggest you pick better and consistent names, like `leftString`, `rightString`, `leftValid`, and `rightValid`.

Answer (score 1):

You've written you're giving the string "5 * 5" - or is it "5*5"? You don't filter out spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [isDigit](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/character_isdigit.htm)() on the char array?

Something like `Character.isDigit(strings[1].charAt(k))` within a loop will tell you if its a digit or not (with handling the * left as an exercise to the poster):

```
String s = "This is string 1";
char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();

for(int x=0;x<charArray.length;x++){
    if(Character.isDigit(charArray[x])){
         System.out.println("True");
    } else {
        System.out.println("FALSE");
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
True
```

Answer (score 0):

`strings[0]` has a value of "5 " so the first pass of the loop sees a 5 and sets valid to true, then the second pass of the loop comes along, sees the space character, and sets it back to false.  You need to come up with a way to handle the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is invalid

```
String[] strings = string.split("\\*");
```

since `string` is not a declared variable in `string.split("\\*");`